# PostgreSQL stored function with multiple queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working on a PostgreSQL function, but having a real struggle with it. It's not my main area so that's probably why, but I wanted to see if this is doable.

I'm trying to create a function to generate records based on year.

In php I'd do something along the lines of:

```
function recordsByYear($year=''){
    $years = array();
    if(empty($year)){
        $sql = "SELECT year FROM myTable GROUP BY year ORDER BY year;";
        $res = $conn->query($sql);
        if($res !== false){
            $data = $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
            foreach($data as $oneYear){
                $years[] = $oneYear;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        $years[] = $year;
    }

    foreach($years as $thisYear){
    //do some queries based on $thisYear
    }
}
```

But I'd like to create a function inside of PostgreSQL, and struggling because I'm not familiar enough with how it all works. I'd like to return a table. I can do some basic stuff, but haven't been able to get something like this working where I have one query then loop through those results running an additional query for each year, then combine the results of that second query and spit out the results as a table.

Comment: Show us sample data and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to guess without more information but you probably need a JOIN

```
SELECT *
FROM ( 
       SELECT DISTINCT year
       FROM myTable 
     ) y 
JOIN ( SELECT year, ... <some query>  
      ....
     ) t
  ON y.year = t.year
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION record_years() RETURNS SETOF int AS $$
  SELECT DISTINCT year FROM myTable ORDER BY 1
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Your PHP code:

```
$sql = "SELECT record_years()";
```

or

```
$sql = "SELECT year FROM record_years() AS year";
```

or alternatively all values in a single row, as a JSON array:

```
$sql = "SELECT array_to_json(ARRAY(SELECT record_years())) AS arr";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
if($res !== false){
  $row = $res->fetch();      
  $years[] = json_decode($row['arr']);
}
```